# Pairs of images before and after retouch/alteration

Tags: data-request, images

I'm looking for a corpus containing pairs of images before and after retouch/alteration.

Example of pair:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I am aware of:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/PhotoshopRequest/
- http://zhopped.com/

Comment: there's a list of similar reddit subs on that page...this twitter, but i think he maybe behind that original sub: https://twitter.com/fjamie013 also this sub not in that sub's list: https://www.reddit.com/r/picrequests/

Comment: actually https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshopbattles/ may be better because all the top level comments on each post are required to contain a link to the photoshopped image.

Comment: Great links, thanks! except for https://twitter.com/fjamie013, I am wasting too much time on it :-)